# CMakeLists.txt cannot find OpenCV and cv_bridge in ROS2

Tags: docker, opencv, cmake, ros, deb

I have a ROS2 package and I create `.deb` packets from it. It worked perfectly until now: locally and in docker container in GitLab pipeline.

Now, after upgrading OpenCV to 4.6.0, I am trying to convert it into debian packet but `bloom-generate rosdebian` cannot find package in CMakeLists.txt in docker in GitLab. On local computer everything works as it did before.

#Problem description in detail:

**Before**:
The ROS2 package used `OpenCV 4.5.4` and `cv_bridge`. The opencv was installed from source and cv_bridge was installed with pip install. The ROS2 package could be build and the .deb packages could be created.

**Now**:
I have upgraded Opencv to `4.6.0` and I am installing `cv_bridge` also **from source** now and not pip install. I can build and test the ROS2 package, but when I generate the .deb packages, it fails saying that it cannot find the `OpenCVConfig.cmake` and `cv_bridgeConfig.cmake` file. **This failure to find packages happens only in GitLab docker, but not on local computer.
Everything worked fine until I upgraded the opencv from 4.5.4 to 4.6.0.***

**I can build and test the ROS2 package but cannot create `.deb` packet because 'bloom-generate` cannot find packages in CMakeLists.txt file.**

I see this error.

```bash
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:56 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" (requested
  version 4.6.0) with any of the following names:
    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake
  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The CMakeLists.txt file could not find the packages. I read the ROS2 and CMake documentations and tried all the following ways mentioned below but none works.

- source the build directory, OpenCVConfig.cmake file, setup.bash file of the OpenCV and cv_bridge installation.
- I have also tried installing the Opencv and cv_bridge at different locations.
- I also tried creating a separate ROS2 workspace containing only OpenCV and cv_bridge and sourcing/adding the WS in the ROS2 packages.
- find_package(OpenCV 4.6.0 REQUIRED)
- find_package(cv_bridge REQUIRED)
- set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/build" ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
- set(opencv_pkg "/opt/ros/humble/src/opencv_pkg")
- include(/opt/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake)
- set(cv_bridge_DIR /opt/vision_opencv)
- set(OpenCV_DIR /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4)
- set(OpenCV_CONFIG "${OpenCV_DIR}/OpenCVConfig.cmake")
- include(${OpenCV_CONFIG})
- include(/home/root/vision_opencv/build/cv_bridge/ament_cmake_core/cv_bridgeConfig.cmake)
- include(/usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake)
- set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4;/home/root/vision_opencv/build/cv_bridge")
- set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/root/vision_opencv/build/cv_bridge ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
- set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4 ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
- include_directories(${cv_bridge_INCLUDE_DIRS})
- include_directories(
  include
  )
- find_package(opencv_pkg REQUIRED PATHS "/opt/ros/humble/src/opencv_pkg" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
- find_package(OpenCV 4.6.0 CONFIG REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4)
- find_package(OpenCV 4.6.0 QUIET)
- find_package(OpenCV 4.6.0 REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4 NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
- find_package(OpenCV 4.6.0 REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS
  opencv_core
  opencv_imgproc
  opencv_imgcodecs
  CONFIG
  )
- target_link_libraries(libpsaf ${OpenCV_LIBS})
- target_include_directories

Comment: So, do you have the file `OpenCVConfig.cmake` in docker? What is exact path to that file?

Comment: @Tsyvarev The file is here: `/usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake`. Also, I gave paths to `OpenCVConfig.cmake` files which are present in the build folder after building opencv from source. When I use the ***path*** options, it cannot find the pacckages, because by default `bloom-generate` looks into this directory for `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file: `usr/lib/x68_64-linux-gnu.`

Comment: Also, the path `usr/lib/x68_64-linux-gnu` already contains an `opencv version 4.5.4 or 4.5d`, which I do not want to use. I think, it comes by defaults with `Ubuntu 22.04`. Then it gives rise to another problem: opencv conflict between two different versions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Oh, they decided to install CMake config files under `lib/cmake/opencv4`, where `find_package(OpenCV)` doesn't search... You could try `find_package(OpenCV NAMES OpenCV4 REQUIRED)` instead. You may also add `--debug-find` option to `cmake` invocation, so CMake will print paths which are searched during `find_package`. (But be ready to a  LOT of output).